# jQuery hide element, load Ajax in it, and then show element

Tags: jquery

I am trying to hide an element, then replace its contents while it's hidden with an ajax `load()`, and as a callback, I would like to show that element again. Unfortunately, after the request completes, the callback is kind of ignored: the element is not shown again.

Here's my code, hope I was clear in my problem:

```
//element is visible
$("#play").hide();//element becomes hidden
$("#play").load("page", function(data){
    $("#play").show();//element should be visible again, but it isn't
});
```

Comment: Does the URL contain an element with the ID "play" (if it does it may cause this issue)?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right. An error happened while making your Ajax call.

- Are you sure your URL is correct?
- `load` requests using the GET method, does your server script allows GET?
- Are you sure there wasn't any error server-side? If this happened, your callback wouldn't execute.

Putting an 'alert' in your inside function will let you show if the request was successful:

```
$("#play").load("page", function(data){
    alert('success');
    $("#play").show();//element should be visible again, but it isn't
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: .load() callback are executed no matter response status

Comment: My request is successful. Therefore, the `#play` contains the requested content from ajax, but it remains invisible.

Answer (score 0):

The url, "page" may also contain an element with the ID, "play".  Try to store the `$("#play")` in a variable.

```
//element is visible
var $play = $("#play");
$play.hide();//element becomes hidden
$play.load("page", function(data){
    $play.show();//element should be visible again, but it isn't
});
```

Comment: Same problem, unfortunately. But I'm pretty sure there isn't any conflict between the URL and the ID.